# Change TFS field-rules via C#

Tags: c#, tfs

I want to acces the field rules of my TFS via C# to add the *AllowedValues* rule a special value.

I have tried some solutions form the MSDN-website but could only contact the fields themselves and not the values of the rules of these.

This is a little experiment if I could connect to my TFS server.

```
// Connect to Team Foundation Server
TfsTeamProjectCollection m_kTFSTeamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(m_sUri));
 m_kTFSTeamProjectCollection.Authenticate();

 WorkItemStore m_kWorkItemStore = (WorkItemStore)m_kTFSTeamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
 Project m_kTeamProject = m_kWorkItemStore.Projects[m_sTeamProject];
```

Comment: Please share some code with us in your question

Comment: Did you try using `witadmin` and modifying the process template XML? That's going to be a lot easier than using C#, if you even can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Daniel said, it's more easier using `witadmin` to export and modify the process template XML if you want to apply work item field rules.

Please see  [Add a rule to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=vsts) and [Import, export, and manage work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=tfs-2018) for details.

However the simplest way is using the **Process Editor** (Power Tools) to export/import or even open and edit the WIT definition file (`*.xml` file) online with GUI.

- [Visual Studio 2015 : [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
  2015 Power Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=vsts)
- Visual Studio 2017 : [TFS Process Template Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-manage-wits?view=tfs-2018)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick help :) I will try this method